# How to send message to rabbitmq correctly from wso2?

Tags: wso2

Hi there I am trying to publish a message from WSO2 to rabbitmq but when I call the API it show me this error `The system cannot infer the transport information from the` -> `url to rabbit with the credentials`
Anybody knows what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

This is the xml of my api.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6zPk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone have the same error, I found out that the deployment.toml file should be have a property like this `sender_enable = true` by default it is in the file but is comment all you have to do is uncomment it  by removing the `#` character